# How to Disable the CTRL+P and Right click in all browsers and i want to display the print button for tracking user?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Disable the CTRL+P and Right click in all browsers and i want to display the print button.if the user clicks print button then only it will work. how to achieve this ?

Comment: Why don't you just use the whole [`annoying.js`](https://kilianvalkhof.com/2011/javascript/annoying-js-how-to-be-an-asshole/)? No? A better alternative would be to use [`beforeprint` event and `matchMedia`](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/) to track printing, however it occurs, without messing up the UX.

Answer (score 1):

To disable right click, write below line of code:

```
 document.oncontextmenu = document.body.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;}
```

To disable ctrl+P, write below lines of code:

```
  jQuery(document).bind("keyup keydown", function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80){
        return false;
    }
});
```